# When is: typedef __intn_t(__INTPTR_WIDTH__) intptr_t; legal? And, why?

Tags: c, xcode

I recently realized that "gcc" and "clang" on my Mac (from Terminal) were searching an Xcode directory for simple include files, like <stdarg.h>.
I discovered that when some simple valid programs (under gcc/clang) failed to compile with tcc (Tiny C) because <stdarg.h> couldn't be found under /usr/include.

Some searching showed that gcc and clang were acting as if there was an implied:

```
-I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include
```

and, indeed stdarg.h is under that directory.  (BTW, nothing in my ENV variables had such a path.)

I provided that path to tcc, and my program still didn't compile, because an error popped up on an interesting line in Xcode's stdint.h

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include/stdint.h has the following:

```
typedef  __intn_t(__INTPTR_WIDTH__)  intptr_t;
```

(and "__INTPTR_WIDTH__" is apparently implicitly defined by the compiler as 64 under -m64, and as 32 under -m32).

However, that would seem to expand to:

```
typedef __intn_t(64)  intptr_t;
```

If I try clang or gcc with such a line, I get (as I expected) a syntax error, just as I do with tcc.

If anyone can tell me why/when that line would be valid, I'd appreciate it.

thanks,

Stan

---

cc -E fum.c              (El Capitan, Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81))

```js
   # 1 "fum.c"
   # 1 "<built-in>" 1
   # 1 "<built-in>" 3
   # 325 "<built-in>" 3
   # 1 "<command line>" 1
   # 1 "<built-in>" 2
   # 1 "fum.c" 2
   # 1 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include/stdint.h" 1 3 4
   # 63 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include/stdint.h" 3 4
   # 1 "/usr/include/stdint.h" 1 3 4
   
   ...250 lines deleted, going in/out of stdint.h, finally dropping back to line 64 of the Xcode version...
   
   # 60 "/usr/include/stdint.h" 2 3 4
   # 64 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include/stdint.h" 2 3 4
   # 2 "fum.c" 2
```

(and that's it, fum.c consisted of one line: #include )
(Sorry it's a snippet ... stackoverflow resisted all my attempts to paste code in ... either manually (4 blank prefixes) or by clicking on the 'code' button ... kept coming out with newlines removed, text reformatted).

Comment: Seems to be an extension from clang or such.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `cc -E file.c` where `file.c` just contains `#include <stdint.h>`?

Comment: Is `__intn_t` defined as a macro somewhere? Something like `#define __intn_t(_N) __intn_t_(_N)` `#define __intn_t_(_N) int##_N##_t`

Comment: @FUZxxl: stackoverflow won't let me paste a comment of 870 chars, so I'm going to try to edit the main question to add it at the end.

Comment: @rici good point.  It is: #define  __intn_t(n) __stdint_join3( int, n, _t)

Comment: @rici, and that points to the solution, thanks!  The solution is that tcc didn't auto define "__INTPTR_WIDTH__" as 64.  Manually defining t fixed it, so I'll add it to my experimental version of tcc.

Answer (score 1):

Question answer pointed to by rici, thanks.  tcc didn't predefine **INTPTR_WIDTH**, so the __intn_t(n) failed to expand as hoped for.

I didn't see a "this answered it" button, so I clicked on "this helped".

thanks!